# Making the reset function for Tic Tac Toe game to work

Tags: javascript, html, tic-tac-toe

I've been working on a short Tic Tac Toe game in Javascript, and all looks good.
However, when I try to add the reset function, it either creates a new table or an element in the button area. My goal is to clear up the table, but I am not sure of an another solution to do that.

**Here, you can see the Javascript code:**

```
const playBoard = document.querySelector("#playboard");
const playerTurn = document.querySelector("#gamerChange");
const winner = document.querySelector("#winnerMessage");

// defining the cells the X and O are going to be placed
let startCells = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

let start = "circle";
// playerTurn.textContent = "Circle goes first";
// winner.textContent = "Circle wins!";

// function to create the whole playboard
function createPlayBoard() {
    startCells.forEach((cell, index) => {
        const cellElement = document.createElement("div");
        cellElement.classList.add("square");
        cellElement.id = index;
        cellElement.addEventListener("click", addElement);
        playBoard.append(cellElement);
    });
}

createPlayBoard();

function addElement(event) {
    const elementDisplay = document.createElement("div");
    elementDisplay.classList.add(start);
    event.target.append(elementDisplay);
    start = start === "circle" ? "cross" : "circle";
    playerTurn.textContent = "It is " + start + "'s turn!";
    event.target.removeEventListener("click", addElement);
    checkTheScore();
}

function checkTheScore() {
    const allSquares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
    const winningCombs = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [2, 5, 8],
    ];

    winningCombs.forEach((array) => {
        const circleWins = array.every((cell) =>
            allSquares[cell].firstChild?.classList.contains("circle")
        );

        if (circleWins) {
            winner.textContent = "Circle wins!";
            playerTurn.textContent = "";

            allSquares.forEach((square) =>
                square.replaceWith(square.cloneNode(true))
            );
            return;
        }
    });

    winningCombs.forEach((array) => {
        const crossWins = array.every((cell) =>
            allSquares[cell].firstChild?.classList.contains("cross")
        );

        if (crossWins) {
            winner.textContent = "Cross wins!";
            playerTurn.textContent = "";

            allSquares.forEach((square) =>
                square.replaceWith(square.cloneNode(true))
            );
            return;
        }
    });
}

function resetGame() {
    const button = document.getElementById("restart");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        startCells = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
        start = "circle";
    });
    checkTheScore();
}
```

**and the HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="text">
        <h1>Welcome to TicTacToe</h1>
        <p id="gamerChange"></p>
        <p id="winnerMessage"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="playboard"></div>

    <button id="restart" onClick="resetGame()">Restart game!</button>

    <!--Javascript file-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for reading this post, I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: The easiest way to reset is using `location.reload()`. Otherwise there are many different approaches. As your code looks identical to a common learning task or homework question, are there any given limitations?

Comment: no, not any limitations, I'm actually building the game to practice Javascript :) and it works haha, thanks a lot!

Comment: Side note: why not indent your code properly?

Comment: You shouldn't use the DOM as your game state. Keep your game state in variables. You started doing that with `startCells`, but then never use its contents.